# Issue with MediaElement.js stuck at Loading

Tags: mediaelement.js

I just starting using MediaElement for audio playback in Chrome and Safari browsers.

I've everything working in my local development environment but when I deploy it on Staging server, MediaElement.js audio player gets stuck at Loading in Safari browser.

Only difference in local and staging server is that staging server is using https(self signed ssl certificate) and local server is using plain http.

I would appreciate any help with this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently (version 8.0), Safari won't load video using an untrusted certificate. If you manually trust the self-signed certificate, the videos will work.